# ReportViewer problema con formato hora al exportar a Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, reportviewer

Programo con Asp. Net y C#.

Tengo varios informes en los que aparecen columnas de un Tablix con información sobre tiempos. Mi problema es que al exportar a Excel este informe no me deja operar con estos tiempos.

Si tengo una columna del Tablix con varios tiempos:

```
0:50
8:00
8:00
3:00
8:00
2:00
0:30
```

Y luego en Excel quiero utilizar la función suma (o la autosuma) de todas estas celdas, me devuelve `0`. Cuando me debería devolver `30:20`.

¿Cómo podría cambiar los formatos desde el Visual Studio (ahora lo hago desde Excel) para poder operar con estas celdas como si fueran tiempos?.

Answer (score 0):

Para sumarlo en excel usas SUMA despues cambia el tipo de formato a [h]:mm:ss
Eso te dara 30:20
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, Salo.Esto es lo que hago, pero aún así la suma me devuelve 0. En el caso de cambiar el formato como dices me devuelve 0:00:00. Ni siquiera me deja cambiar el formato de las celdas con los tiempos que tengo que sumar (por ejemplo, si quisiera que en vez de 0:50 me apareciese 0:50:00, no me deja). No me deja hacer nada con las celdas. También me pasa con una columna de fechas que tengo, tampoco me deja cambiarle el formato. Si aparece como 25-07-2017 y quiero que aparezca como 25-Abr-2017, tampoco me deja cambiar el formato. No se... es raro...